# How to get values from database to jcombobox?

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

I have tried to retrieve data from MySQL database into JComboBox but I haven't got it because when I write an isbn into a JTextField to search a book, appear all the ids for 4 times and finally appear the ids which I want but for 2 times. I want to get data into JComboBox just the ids which have the isbn which I am searching, boxBookId is my JComboBox. I use NetBeans. Can someone to help me? Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
private void fieldIsbnKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/library";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT id, book, author FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%" +fieldIsbn.getText()+ "%' ";
        String sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(isbn) FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%" +fieldIsbn.getText()+ "%' ";

        pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        pstm2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
        rs2 = pstm2.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            boxBookId.addItem(rs.getString("id"));
            String val1 = rs.getString("book");
            fieldBook.setText(val1);
            String val2 = rs.getString("author");
            fieldAuthor.setText(val2);
        }
        while (rs2.next()) {  
                fieldAvailableBooks.setText(rs2.getString(1));
        } 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: _never_ (I really mean it) construct sql queries with parameters like this. This is far too vulnerable to SQL attacks. Ok, if it's a desktop application with it's own database the user might just kill her own data - but you should make a good habit of always sanitizing/escaping parameters for queries. Better use a `PreparedStatement` and add the parameters there.

Comment: As for your problem: I only see you adding elements to `boxBookId`. I'd suggest removing the old ones before adding the query results.

Comment: @Thomas I don't understand how you say I do. Can you modify my code or give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, what do you want an example for? I'd have to add it as an answer though for formatting reasons.

Comment: @thomas I want an example for my code or a solution because I am beginner and I am blocked here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove any existing elements before adding the results of your query to `boxBookId`, e.g. by calling `boxBookId.removeAllItems()` right before the while-loop (to prevent removing them if the query fails).

As for the security issue I mentioned (you should really read up on this yourself), use a `PreparedStatement` to set the parameters (construct it only once and reuse it):

```
//outside your method: construct this only once and reuse inside your method
pstm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, book, author FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE ?");

//in your method:
pstm.setString(1, "%" + fieldIsbn.getText() + "%" );
rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

As you can see I reused the `PreparedStatement` `pstm` that you already created. The key is to reuse it and use it to set the parameters. Otherwise using a `PreparedStatement` doesn't make much sense (what I mean is directly appending parameter values to the SQL and recreating the statement before every call).